# Zend2 Post Request

Tags: php, http, curl, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to do a POST request to an endpoint with Zend2.

I can do the post in PHP using Curl, but cannot reproduce that Curl request using Zend2 Client and Request.

For example, the following works fine.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$postfields = array();
$postfields['CostCode'] = '999999801';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
          $postfields);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; 
charset=UTF-8',
                                        'Connection: Keep-Alive'
                                        ));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Result returned:-

```
<ValidateCCResult xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<Result>1</Result></ValidateCCResult>
```

Indicating that the costcode is valid.

But, when I try and reproduce this in Zend, I don't get the response I expect.

```
    $postfields = array();
    $postfields['CostCode'] = '999999801';

    $client = new \Zend\Http\Client();

    $client->setAdapter(new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl());

    $request = new \Zend\Http\Request();

    $request->setUri($url);
    $request->setMethod(\Zend\Http\Request::METHOD_POST);
    $request->getHeaders()->addHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'
    ]);

    $request->setContent($postfields);

    $response = $client->dispatch($request);

<ValidateCCResult xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><Result>0</Result>
<Message/></ValidateCCResult>
```

I have tried different content-types, but have a feeling it is something to do with setContent changing the array of $postfields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
$postfields['CostCode'] = '999999801';
$uri                    = 'http://localhost';

$client = new \Zend\Http\Client();
$client->setUri($uri);
$client->setMethod('POST');
$client->setOptions(array(
    'keepalive'   => true,
));
$client->setEncType(\Zend\Http\Client::ENC_FORMDATA);

$client->setParameterPost($postfields);
$response = $client->send();

echo $response->getBody();
```

Comment: Afraid not. I tried with this as well, but no luck. $client->setOptions(array(
                'charset' => 'UTF-8',
                'Content-Type' =>  'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'
            ));

Comment: Add in question, what result you suppose to get and what exactly is wrong in result.

Comment: Updated. The API doesn't help by not giving any feedback, but a zero indicates that the validation failed, which I know is not correct and the plain old Curl validates fine.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: That's it, it works! Setting the EngType did the trick. Spent all Friday trying to solve this and you fixed within 10 minutes Monday. Good Karma all day for you Zen.